# Elastic search exact match

Tags: elasticsearch, exact-match

I'm using elasticsearch and am having a devil of a time getting an exact match to happen. I've tried various combinations of match, query_string, etc, and I either get nothing or bad results. 
Query looks like this:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "term": "dog",
      "type": "main"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "term": "Dog"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

Sorted results

```
10.102211 {u'term': u'The Dog', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': 7730506}
10.102211 {u'term': u'That Dog', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': 4345664}
10.102211 {u'term': u'Dog', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': 144}
7.147442 {u'term': u'Dog Eat Dog (song)', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': u'5288184'}
```

I see, of course that "The Dog", "That Dog" and "Dog" all have the same score, but I need to figure out how I can boost the exact match "Dog" in score.

I also tried

```
{
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "term": "Dog"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "term": {
              "query": "Dog",
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "term": "dog",
      "type": "main"
    }
  }
}
```

but that still just gives me

```
11.887239 {u'term': u'The Dog', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': 7730506}
11.887239 {u'term': u'That Dog', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': 4345664}
11.887239 {u'term': u'Dog', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': 144}
8.410372 {u'term': u'Dog Eat Dog (song)', u'type': u'main', u'conceptid': u'5288184'}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fields are analyzed with the standard analyzer by default. If you would like to check exact match, you could store your field not analyzed also e.g:

```
"dog":{
            "type":"multi_field",
            "fields":{
                "dog":{
                    "include_in_all":false,
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "store":"no"
                },
                "_tokenized":{
                    "include_in_all":false,
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"analyzed",
                    "store":"no"
                }
            }
        }
```

Then you can query the dog-field for exact matches, and dog._tokenized for analyzed queries (like fulltext)

Comment: Would this require making a change to all the records? I've got about just shy of 50,000,000 (very small) records in this index. Or would it make more sense to nuke the index and reimport with this structure in place as appropriate? I'm a newbie when it comes to Lucene stuff, if I stored my data like this, how would my ES queries change? Thanks for your help! I was going to ask about the best way to design my index here but I'll make that another question I think.

Comment: This was what I needed, I ended up rebuilding the data anyhow as I wanted to get at it in a different way, but I used this as the basis of my approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that field `term` is being analyzed (check your mapping) with the standard analyzer and is filtering stopwords such as `the` or `that`. For that reason you get the same score for `Dog` and `The Dog`. So maybe you can solve your problem by configuring a custom analyzer => [documentation page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/custom-analyzer/)

Answer (score -1):

Hash two value which you need to search into hash key, then search it.