# How to do mapping while indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am using `ElasticSearch` in a website where i index data from `MongoDB`.

```
def postToEs(self):
    """
    put data to the elasticsearch
    """
    es = Elasticsearch()
    cursor = self.getMongoData()
    for document in cursor:
        esdoc={}
        esdoc["category"] = document.get("category")
        esdoc["description"] = document.get("description")
        esdoc["title"] = document.get("title")
        esdoc["link"] = document.get("link")
        esdoc["state"] = document.get("state")
        esdoc_id = esdoc["link"]
        es.index(
            index = 'news',
            doc_type = 'allnews',
            id = esdoc_id,
            body = json.dumps(esdoc)
        )
```

This worked good. But currently I have to search in the `state` field for an exact match in `elasticsearch`. Currently if I search for entries for `New York` it also gives result of `New Hampshire`. I have found [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598418/elastic-search-exact-match) and saw elasticsearch documentation that I need to add `mapping` on the data. My question is how do I add a mapping on the data in the current scenario? or is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: 1) we can add new field to mapping . but we cannot modify mapping after indexing. we need to re index. pls provide your current mapping.. Then i ll help you

Comment: current mapping is like this
`{"allnews":{"properties":{"category":{"type":"string"},"description":{"type":"string"},"link:{"type":"string"},"state":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"}}}}`

Comment: i need to map the `state` as `"state":{"type":"string","index" : "not_analyzed"}`

Comment: if I re index how do i specify the mapping. As i am new in Elasticsearch i don't know very much about it's query syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Delete the existing index**

```
curl -XDELETE "http://hostname:9200/index/type"
```

**Delete the existing river config index**

```
curl -XDELETE "http://hostname:9200/_river"
```

**Create mapping to index**

```
curl -XPUT "http://hostname:9200/index/type/_mapping" -d'
{
"allnews": {
    "properties": {
        "category": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "link": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
            "type": "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
}'
```

After these steps put the river plugin config sync mongodb to elasticsearch.

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: Thank you. Actually I solved it already the same way you have specified here. Is there any way of doing this from python script?