# Elasticsearch match query with partial text match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

Newbie question on elasticsearch. I have set up the elasticsearch lucene index and use searching for names that contain some term, such as

```
search_response = es.search(index = 'sample', body = {'query':{'match':{'first_name':"JUST"}}})
```

This does not return me the name "JUSTIN" but the following query does

```
search_response = es.search(index = 'sample', body = {'query':{'match':{'first_name':"JUSTIN"}}})
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't "match" query return me the records that contain the term?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch: Find substring match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243867/elasticsearch-find-substring-match)

Comment: No, `match query` will not get you records when you search for `JUST`. you can try with JUST* in `wildcard query`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle that need is by creating a custom analyzer which uses the [edgeNGram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html). Forget about wildcards and using `*` in query strings, those all underperform the edgeNGram approach.

So you'd have to create your index like this first and then reindex your data into it.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/sample -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "prefixes": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 15
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "prefixes"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "your_type": {
            "properties": {
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then when indexing `first_name: JUSTIN`, you'll get the following indexed tokens: `j`, `ju`, `jus`, `just`, `justi`, `justin`, basically all prefixes of JUSTIN.

You'll then be able to search with your second query and actually find what you expect.

```
search_response = es.search(index = 'sample', body = {'query':{'match':{'first_name':'JUST'}}})
```

Comment: Did this help? Do you need more info?