# Handle large amount of shards in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

Every shop has its own set of inventory which is stored in elasticsearch as one index.  Currently, I have 11 thousand shops that mean it has 11 thousand shards with indices which are difficult to fetch data in 32 GB ram server.

Can someone guide how to store an inventory of every shop in elasticsearch as creating separate indices for every shop inventory is not helping me?

Below are the mappings of the index. Elasticsearch version using is 6.0.1

```
{
  "staging_shop_inventory_558" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "shop_inventory" : {
        "properties" : {
          "alternate_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "brand" : {
            "properties" : {
              "created_at" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "image" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "index" : false
              },
              "is_selected" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "standard"
              },
              "updated_at" : {
                "type" : "date"
              }
            }
          },
          "brand_autocomplete" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search"
          },
          "brand_suggest" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "ngram_analyzer"
          },
          "category" : {
            "properties" : {
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "image" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "index" : false
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "standard"
              }
            }
          },
          "created_at" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "deleted_at" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "image" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : false
          },
          "is_deleted" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            },
            "analyzer" : "gramAnalyzer",
            "search_analyzer" : "whitespace_analyzer"
          },
          "name_autocomplete" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search"
          },
          "name_suggest" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "ngram_analyzer"
          },
          "product_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "product_sizes" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "deleted_at" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "description" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "ean_code" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "in_stock" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "is_deleted" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "price" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "product_id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "product_update_on" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "product_update_status" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "uom" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              },
              "weight" : {
                "type" : "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "sub_category" : {
            "properties" : {
              "created_at" : {
                "type" : "date"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "image" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "index" : false
              },
              "is_selected" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "standard"
              },
              "updated_at" : {
                "type" : "date"
              }
            }
          },
          "sub_category_suggest" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "gramAnalyzer",
            "search_analyzer" : "whitespace_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow having 11k shards(there might be more based on the replica factor) in your node which has just 32 GB RAM(again note this is not the JVM allocated to Elasticsearch process) whose performance greatly depends on the JVM size and [beyond 32GB deteriorates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html).

Elasticsearch is a distributed system and can be easily scaled to thousands of nodes, you should add more nodes in your cluster and distribute your Elasticsearch indices to all the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest how can create a better system using elasticsearch instead creating so many indices as in future shops are going to increase by 10x so it will be difficult to handle so many shards?

Comment: @BeenaShetty, it depends on various factor, you can have multiple shops data in single index(if documents are not huge in each shops), what are your functional and non-functional requirements (refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584211/4039431 ) and share your details in followup questions so that it's easy to answer and would be helpful to community.

Comment: @BeenaShetty also please refer https://www.linkedin.com/posts/biancalewis_10-important-tips-to-improve-search-in-elasticsearch-activity-6671356563535499264-CZc6/ for great and short tips to improve search performance of Elasticsearch.