# How to do partial search and get relevant score in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-emr

I am new to Elasticsearch, trying to do some search.
I have names of objects like :

```
Homework
work
jobroles
jobs
```

I am using wildcard query, but its returning score of 1.0 for each docs.

I want score based on how well it matched. Ex

**Ex. If I type**

> work

```
score of work > homework
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a good question and directly you can't get the exact match on top, what you need is ngram analyzer which provides the partial matches and another field which stores the exact tokens in lowercase(text field with standard analyzer will solve it).

I've reproduced your issue and solved it using above mentioned approach, Please refer [my blog on autocomplete](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/) and my [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584211/4039431) for in-depth read of various autocomplete/partial searches and why/what/how part of it.

### Working example

**Create index mapping**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "index.max_ngram_diff" : 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
      },
      "title_lowercase" :{
        "type" : "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index your sample docs**

```
{
  "title" : "Homework",
  "title_lowercase" : "Homework"
}   

{
  "title" : "work",
  "title_lowercase" : "work"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "work"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title_lowercase": {
              "query": "work"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**And expected result**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "internaledge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
      "_score": 0.9926754, /note score of `work` is much higher than`homework`
        "_source": {
          "title": "work",
          "title_lowercase": "work"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "internaledge",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2995283,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Homework",
          "title_lowercase": "Homework"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: salam.I am getting this error while trying to create index : https://justpaste.it/8do6n

Comment: @Imran, are you creating index from fresh ?

Comment: yes, i fixed that issue. "doc" was missing.

its working good, thanks.

for examle i have names like work,homework,homeworkinformation

searching for information gives me no result,where as info did. Any idea what should be the good size of ngram ?

Comment: sure, One last thing, is it possible to apply these new settings to existing index ?

Comment: yes, but you have to first close and than open the index :) use the API mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219399/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-imran).

Comment: is it possible to create the ngrams like this : homework -> ho,hom,home,homew,homewo,homewor,homework only ? which is only in forward direction ?
And thanks for the help last time, I got good grades in the assignment :-)
@Opster

Comment: @Imran thats great to hear to that got good marks and yeah its totally possible, would advise you to ask a new question and I shall post the answer there, please comment here as soon as you ask a question :)

Comment: here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423787/how-to-create-ngrams-in-only-forward-direction-in-elasticsearch