# ElasticSearch search results with variable values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-7

I'm looking to use elasticsearch for a search bar with autocompletion feature.
I have a set of questions and they have multiples variables that I'd like to substitute with other values.

A template of a question would be: Do you like FIELDS?
with FIELDS replaced by math, physics, history
and then when querying the question "do you like", it would show multiple hits:

- do you like math?
- do you like physics?
- do you like history?

I saw elasticseach as a synonyms analyzer and thought it could be used for this use case but it doesn't seem to work like I expected. Here's below what I have so far.

create the index

```
{
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "my_field": {
                    "type": "search_as_you_type",
                    "analyzer": "standard",
                    "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "synonym_analyzer": {
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": ["my_synonyms"]
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "my_synonyms": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "FIELDS => math, physics, history"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

query

```
{
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": partial_question,
                "type": "bool_prefix",
                "fields": [
                    "my_field",
                    "my_field._2gram",
                    "my_field._3gram",
                    "my_field._index_prefix"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is one result "Do you like FIELDS?"

Comment: Is it possible to have an example of your desired output? I am having some confusion to understand. If I understood your issue well, if you search for a particular value, it should return "Do you like Math?" alongside with the other hits[Physic and history]

Comment: Yes, the desired output is to have the
do you like math?
do you like physics?
do you like history?
when I have the `partial question` is "do you like"

Comment: @Ffloriel , could you please have a look at my answer and let me know if you have follow-up related questions, as shown in my answer it solves the question asked in question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@hansley answer would work but as wildcard queries are costly, you could simply use the [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) without changing anything in your index.

Although there are various ways to implement Autosuggest in ES and considering its importance and popularity I've written a [detailed blog on various approaches and their trade-off](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/) Also my [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584211/4039431) could give you information on functional and non-function requirements to build an Autosuggest feature.

**End to end example using prefix query:**

Default index mapping, which creates a `.keyword field` for each text field:

Index sample docs:

```
{
  "title" : "i like red car"
}

{
  "title" : "do you like math?"
}

{
  "title" : "do you like physics?"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "title.keyword": {
        "value": "do you like"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search results**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "partialpre",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "do you like math?"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "partialpre",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "do you like physics?"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your issue well, I did a suggested answers which you may use. I used the wildcard query alongside a normalizer to lowercase all the values:

Here is the mapping of my index:

```
PUT multiple-fields
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type":"custom",
        "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
        
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "quest":{
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ingested the following data in the index:

"quest":"do you like math?"

"quest":"do you like physics?"

"quest":"do you like history?"

"quest":"I think i do like you"

"quest":"I like red car"

"quest":"do you not like"

"quest":"Do you like math?"

Based on the values, I created the following query:

```
GET multiple-fields/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "quest": {
        "value": "do you like*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response was:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "multiple-fields",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "bue1e3QBsTCl1BZvB0by",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "quest" : "do you like math?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "multiple-fields",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "cOe1e3QBsTCl1BZvD0Yh",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "quest" : "do you like physics?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "multiple-fields",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "cee1e3QBsTCl1BZvE0Zq",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "quest" : "do you like history?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "multiple-fields",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2-e1e3QBsTCl1BZvLUak",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "quest" : "Do you like math?"
    }
  }
]
```

Links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Note: However, it might affect the performance if you are using a wildcard

Let me know if it would help you, else we can work on another solution thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking in the wrong direction with the synonym.
What you want is a [suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-completion.html).
You will have a little specific work to do but you will be able to create very powerful suggestions for your uses cases.