# Elastic Search - document text search

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, elasticsearch

Im considering using elastic search for a new project.

My projects going to be hosted in azure and the part im looking to use elastic search for is for the user to be able to upload text documents and be able to search the documents by partial matches and priortise which documents are most likely to be matches.

Is elastic search the correct thing to use?

Is elastic search its own document db or does it need connecting to mongo db or something similar that can also be hosted in azure?

Comment: If you rather want a PaaS service than hosting elastic yourself, you might also look into Azure Cognitive Search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has its own storage(so no need to have MongoDB or other storage) and you can install it on any bare-metal machine(you just need to have a server in azure to install ES).

For partial search using Elasticsearch please refer to my [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584211/4039431) for functional and non-functional requirements.

You can also refer to my [detailed blog on various approaches](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-auto-complete-guide/) to implement partial-search in ES.