# ElasticSearch mapping dates

Tags: elasticsearch

First time using ElasticSearch, I'm having trouble indexing a document due to the mapping of dates.

in my DB dates are `DATETIME` and look like this `2014-02-04 14:04:39`. I'm trying to parse this in ElasticSearch but it's telling me that

`[Invalid format: \"2014-02-04 14:04:39\" is malformed at \" 14:04:39\"]`

I've tried setting the format quite a few different ways:

```
'date_added' => array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
        )
```

and also like this:

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZ`

What is the correct format for this?

Comment: Did you check if your mapping was successful? Did you apply the mapping before inserting any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mapping, configure the field to date and also the format you need.. For syntax refer

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#date

The date format that are supported by elasticsearch refer the following link..

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: thanks for those, I had looked at them but I don't see what is wrong with my format that I've tried. But obviously it is wrong, but I don't know what the correct format should be.

Comment: To change mapping.. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238972/how-to-do-mapping-while-indexing-in-elasticsearch/23241214#23241214

Comment: I changed my format to `'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'` and this worked for me.